# Adding dynamic ltr and rtl directions inside splide js slider

Tags: alpine.js, splidejs

I am using alpine js in my project. I added i18n to subpport both arabic and English languages.

when I change the language, I added this code to change all layout from ltr to rtl.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPki8.png)

Splide js is working well when i have English langaue, but when I change to Arabic, it did not work.

My final goal is this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRzUO.png)

Note: When I add this as hard code, it works but i need to change this based on Language selection.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4lMe.png)

My final goal is this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRzUO.png)

Comment: Please post the code as text, not a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

use "direction" keyword instead of "dir" in the mounting of the slider, it works for me!